# How to render multiple components with different component name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a few components, they have the same parameter with iterative values, like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Panel from "./Panel";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Panel id={1} />
      <Navbar id={2} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const Panel = ({ id }) => {
  return (
     <div>The id is {id}</div>
  );
};
```

```
const Navbar = ({ id }) => {
  return (
     <div>The id is {id}</div>
  );
};
```

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-pond-mpnnp

Now I'd like to use `map` to render those components at once in `App.js`, something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const compnentArray = ['Panel', 'Navbar'];
  const RenderComponents = () => {
    let _o = [];
    return (
      componentArray.map((item, index) => _o.push(<{item} id={index} />))
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {RenderComponents()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

So that `item` renders component names. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this working for you or do you see any issues? Have you looked into the `key` attribute for each mapped component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could make use of `Array.map()`'s second parameter which gives you the index in the array:

```
import React from "react";
import Panel from "./Panel";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const components = [Panel, Navbar];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {components.map((Component, i) => (
        <Component key={i} id={i + 1} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

As mentioned in [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime), to render a component dynamically, just make sure you assign it to a variable with a capital first letter and use it like you'd use any other component.

Comment: Quite shocked to see that `<Component ... />` is recognised by React and `Component` just equals to Panel and Navbar in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";
import Panel from "./Panel";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const components = [Panel, Navbar]; // notice you are using the components as items, not strings;

/*
if the components need props from the parent,
the `renderComponents()` function should be declared
inside the parent component (and possibly with a `useCallback()`
hook, to avoid unnecessary re-declarations on re-renders)
*/
function renderComponents() {
  return components.map((comp, index) => <comp key={index} id={index} />) || null;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderComponents()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could swap strings with your actual component references and itererate over them directly in your JSX part, like this :

```js
 export default function App() {
  const componentsArray = [Panel, Navbar];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {componentsArray.map((Component, index) => <Component key={index} id={index + 1} />)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Though I would suggest to memoize them to improve performance once you're confortable enough with React to start using memoization.